# Adobe air mobile: Set VIEW Title visible false in Tabbed Navigator application

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

I have TabbedViewNavigatorApplication with some viewnaviagtor on the bottom, also all views have title on the top of the screen.

How to remove title from application - how to set visible true/false? 
How to manipulate this visibility on landscape/portrait view?

I want to set visible off on landscape mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                  initialize="appInit(event)"
                                  splashScreenImage="@Embed('images/st_logo.png')"
                                  splashScreenMinimumDisplayTime="300"
                                  >


    <s:ViewNavigator id="viewMap" icon="@Embed('images/ico_map.png')" click="viewMap_clickHandler(event)"  width="100%" height="100%"  firstView="views.MapView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="viewConfig" icon="@Embed('images/ico_tool.png')" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.ConfigView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="viewSim" icon="@Embed('images/ico_sim.png')" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.SimView"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
```

on view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="Mapa" 
        destructionPolicy="never"
        xmlns:maps="pl.com.tiger.herringMobile.components.maps.*"
        tabBarVisible="{actionBarVis}"
        middleClick="toggleActionBar()"
        menuKeyPressed="toggleActionBar()"
        initialize="viewMapa_initializeHandler(event)" xmlns:buttons="pl.com.tiger.herring.components.buttons.*">
```

I can set tabBarVisible - but this only turn on/off bottom navigator tabs - not the view title.
How to turn off view title ?

---

Ok, it solved - http://devgirl.org/2011/05/23/flex-4-5-mobile-application-development-controlling-visibility-actionbar-tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `actionBarVisible` to false

Comment: http://devgirl.org/2011/05/23/flex-4-5-mobile-application-development-controlling-visibility-actionbar-tabs/

exacly, you have right